# What is the default launcher on the Moto G?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-y, motorola-moto-g

Does the default launcher on Moto G resemble the Holo launcher? I suspect the Motorola Migrate has done a number on my Moto G.

I migrated from an old Samsung Galaxy Y and this ***may have*** caused a lot of the settings to go awry. For instance, I do not have a rooted phone, but I have the Rootbrowser and the SuperUser app on my Moto G.

Similarly I have a launcher which resembles the Holo launcher on my Samsung Galaxy Y. I have not yet familiarized myself with 4.3 Android and I will be getting there soon.

In the meantime, I just wanted to know what does the default launcher on the Moto G look like?

Comment: I've answered the question regarding the launcher. As for your other questions, you may want to ask them individually. It's quite possible that Migrate moved the SuperUser app and Rootbrowser, but you are **still not rooted**. The apps can be installed, but will simply not be fully functional without root.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The launcher on the Moto G is indeed almost identical to the stock Android Launcher - but not the Google Experience launcher that is seen on Nexus devices running Android 4.4+.